# ならでは vs. ぐらいのもの

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, jlpt, word-usage

I understand that both means to emphasize the uniqueness of the word before it (i.e. "only ~") but in the following sentence, I don't know which one fits.

> この難しい手術ができるのは、渡辺先生＿＿のものだ。

Both ならでは and ぐらい seem to make sense.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`～ならではの + noun` is a set phrase meaning "(noun) only seen in ～", "(noun) unique to ～", "(noun) that can be done only by ～", etc. For example, you can say 渡辺先生ならではの手術, which means "surgery that can only be performed by Dr. Watanabe." (BTW, ならでは is read ならで**わ**)

Now, this sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) where the person name is focused. When you say "この難しい手術ができるのは", a noun (phrase) **representing a person** is expected after it. And 渡辺先生ならではのもの doesn't qualify as the noun phrase representing a person.

In other words, using ならでは is wrong because it would literally mean something like <sup>[×]</sup>"The person who can perform this difficult surgery is the thing that can be done only by Dr. Watanabe."

`くらい/ぐらい (+ の/な + もの)` is interchangeable with だけ in cleft sentences like this.

If you want to use ならでは, you can say 「この難しい手術は渡辺先生ならではのものだ」「これは渡辺先生ならではの難しい手術だ」, etc.