# くらい in 「昔からあるのは、角のたばこやさんくらいだ」

Tags: grammar, particle-くらい

> 子: あれ？お父さん、このあいだまでとうふ屋さんがあったところに、新しい建物がたっているよ。
> 父: うん。とうふ屋さんは、つぶれちゃったんだ。ハンバーガーショップができたみたいだね。
> 子:　やった！ぼく、ハンバーガー大好き！
> 父:　お父さんは、さびしいな。お父さんが小さいころからあったからね。商店街も、だいぶ変わってしまったなあ。**昔からあるのは、角のたばこやさんくらいだ。**
> 子: あそこのスーパーも、昔からあったの？
> 父: たしか、昔は銭湯だったな。そうそう、ときどきお風呂あがりに牛乳を買って飲んだよ。

I have a question about the use of くらい in that bolded text. I know くらい/ぐらい has the meaning of "about" or "to extent that...". How is the meaning of くらい exactly applied in this situation?

I am assuming that it shows a limit to what was in 商店街 before? So "there were things like 角のたばこやさん before (and maybe more)"? Is this interpretation correct?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/34287/9831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The くらい means...

> ❸ 低い程度の物事を示して、**せいぜいそれだけと限定する**意を表す。
> 「せめて日曜日くらい休みたい」

(from 明鏡国語辞典)

---

> 昔からある**のは**、角のたばこやさん**くらい**だ。

この「ぐらい」と同じ用法です：

> この難しい手術ができる**のは**、渡辺先生**ぐらい**のものだ。

( [ならでは vs. ぐらいのもの](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/34280/9831) より)

ナルトさんの説明を抜粋しますと、

> `くらい/ぐらい (+ の/な + もの)` is interchangeable with だけ in cleft sentences like this.