# Difference between かわいいのは私です and かわいいの私です?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, nuances, syntax

Can someone **check** and **explain the difference**, along with **literal translations**, between these two sentences for me?

かわいいのは私です and かわいいの私です.

I got the former as an answer to one of my questions and came up with the latter after reading an article about no-adjectives. I believe they both mean the same thing, but I'm not too sure because of the は particle and when given more context.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The former, かわいいのは私です is correct, and means "It is me who is cute." It's a *cleft sentence* made from a very simple sentence 私はかわいいです ("I am cute"). See [this answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) for details about cleft sentences. This の functions as a "placeholder", like *it* in "*It* is me who is cute."

かわいい is a typical ***i*-adjective**, and it doesn't work as a no-adjective or a noun. かわいいの私です doesn't make sense.