# What does the の do in 向かっているのは特別棟?

Tags: particle-の, manga

Two characters are walking a corridor in a school, and the following appears in two thought bubbles around one of them.

渡り廊下を越えるって事は

向かっているのは特別棟か

How can 特別棟 be a statement about 向かっているの? As far as I know, the の particle after a verb can mean requiring or giving explanation, or it can make a noun out of a verb. Can it make 向かっているの mean "the place toward which we're going"?

Comment: here の nominalizes [= let's you use a verb or verb-expression as a noun grammatically] (see http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nominalization)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This pattern is so common that it has a special name, a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010).

> 向かっている**のは**特別棟か。
>   So **it's** Special Building **that** we're heading to.

`verb + のは + whatever + だ/です` is a basic pattern of cleft sentences, and it's similar to `it's + whatever + that/who + verb` pattern in English. の here is something like a dummy pronoun, and 特別棟 is the word that is focused.

Here か is a kind of "surprise" marker ([see the 6th definition under 終助 here](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/34861/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%8B/)), which is used in place of だ because it's a new piece of information the speaker got just now. (eg. 君か。 "Oh, it's you!")