# How is v-ta no used?

Tags: particle-の, nominalization

Could someone explain the construction **v-ta no**?
I saw it in the article title

> 東京などで雪　１１月に降ったのは５４年前

Comment: I could understand the meaning of the sentence. I wasn't sure why <no> was used there (I wrongly thought it formed a construsction with the verb before it) . Having checked what nominalizers could do it seems it refers to the whole first part of the title <東京などで雪>. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This の is a nominalizer, but more specifically, this can be understood as a marker that introduces [cleft-sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19204/5010), which are used to focus some part of the sentence.

> - (雪が) 54年前に 11月に 降った。
>     Snow fell in November 54 years ago.
> - (雪が) 11月に 降った **の** は 54年前だ。
>     It's 54 years ago that snow fell in November. (54年前 is focused)

だ/です at the end is omitted because it's a news title which is expected to be short.

To be clear, this type of の does not have to follow the ta-form of a verb.

> - この映画を初めて見ます。
>     I see this movie for the first time.
> - この映画を見る**の**は初めてです。
>     It's the first time that I see this movie. (初めて is focused)

Answer (score 3):

This の functions as a nominalizer of the sentence

> 東京などで雪が１１月に降った
>   Snow fell around Tokyo in November

The rest of the title talks about this sentence:

> 東京などで雪が１１月に降ったのは５４年前
>   Snow falling in and around Tokyo in November [was last] 54 years ago

or, more idiomatically,

> The last time it snowed in November in and around Tokyo was 54 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a special construct going on here, just a sentence modifying a noun, and that noun being replaced by の due to reference locality.

In 「１１月に降った[の]{雪}は５４前」,「の」is used to refer back to 「雪」from 「東京などで雪」, modified by 「１１月に降った」.

As a whole, the headline reads roughly: "Snow in Tokyo and surroundings – First time in 54 years"

Comment: (I didn't downvote you, but) I don't think the way you interpret the grammar is correct. I would say it's something like （最後に）東京などで雪（が）11月に降ったのは５４年前（だった）.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Yep, I'd say you're probably right. Fixing.

Comment: @Earthliŋ Although, if it's the first time in 54 years, it's also _technically_ more than fell in any November in the same period. ;)