# Help understanding 「そのタイトルのリストに次に載るのは俺だ」

Tags: grammar, meaning, cleft-sentences

I've been reading this Japanese wrestling results site http://jabroni.typepad.jp/wwe/2016/10/20161024-raw.html and I'm having trouble understanding this sentence:

> そのタイトルのリストに次に載るのは俺だ。

from this paragraph:

> Chris、では今からこのリストを返そう。でもその前に、新しいリストを作ろう。WWE UniversalチャンピオンのKevin Owens、お前はHIACでタイトルマッチをすれば、タイトルを失うことになる。俺は必ずそのベルトを盗んでやる。**そのタイトルのリストに次に載るのは俺だ**。

Is it saying that his going to put the title (belt) on the list next? Is it normal the sentence ordering with 僕だ at the end of the sentence? I don't understand the structure of this sentence.

Comment: Could you make 2 questions instead of asking 2 problems at one question...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes 俺だ can be placed at the end of a sentence.

> そのタイトルのリストに次に載るのは俺だ。
>   It's me who will appear on the list of the title (holders) next time.

This is a rather simple [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) which was constructed from:

> 俺はそのタイトルのリストに次に載る。
>   I will appear on the list of title holders next time.

Comment: Omg I was losing my head on this one, thank you so much. The problem with this site is that they add things to the translation that wasn't on the original broadcast, that's why I couldn't figure out