# Problem with のが in this sentence

Tags: grammar

そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**のが**地図Aである。
https://www.docdroid.net/847v2dg/img-20170413-0001-new.pdf.html
The sentence is from Line 5 in the above linked text.

the problem lies with のが. I don't really understand why it is there. I usually would expect the sentence to be like this:
そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た地図Aである
=> "Therefore, the map A is there, which McArthur tried to craft by himself."
or "Therefore the McArthur tried to craft by himself map A is there" in a more literal way.

In this very chapter, my textbook taught me that a sentence element further determining another sentence element can be marked through both が and の, like here:
留学生  が/の  描いた絵を見ました。

But nowhere has it been said that both can be used at the same time xD
So, apart from the fact that I really don't see why が or の have to be there at all, I understand even less why both of them are there...^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This type of sentence is called a [*cleft sentence*](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19204/5010). This の works as a placeholder just like "it" in English cleft sentences. This is a very common pattern. See the link for details and lots of similar examples (linked under "Related" section).

> マッカーサーは地図Aを作ってみた。
>   McArthur tried making Map A.
>
> マッカーサーが作ってみた**のは**地図Aである。
>   **It is** Map A **that** McArthur tried making.
>
> マッカーサーが作ってみたの**が**地図Aである。 (exhaustive-listing *ga*)
>   It is Map A (among others) that McArthur tried making.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Provided a superb explanation together with the link :)
About の: Aside from it's function as a placeholder, it technically works as a nominalizer too, right? Otherwise I couldn't see how the preceding sentence element shall interact with は/が ^^

Comment: Yes の also works as a nomilanizer, but in this construction, の does not represent a preceding verb (="creating") itself. It represents anything that's focused and related to the verb. In this case, it represents not 作ってみる but 地図A.

Comment: @Narktor If you call it "norminalizer" or not depends on grammar theories.

Comment: Can one say that the two parts/sides
マッカーサーが作ってみたの
(が)
地図Aである
form a predicative construction then?

what I mean becomes more clear when one replaces "it" with "the thing", although I don't know wether that's still legitimate or goes too far:
"*The thing* (,that) McArthur tried making, *is map A*"

This came to my mind when I reiterated on my translation of the full sentence and found that "Thereupon, *the thing* (that) McArthur tried making *is Map A*" sounds a bit better than "Thereupon, it is Map A (that) McArthur tried making." 
But my preferences might mean nothing here ^^

Answer (score 3):

This の is an "empty" noun - a noun in form and function but with no content/meaning. It is always modified by a sentence (of theoretically any length, from a single word up)  and takes on the meaning of that modifying word or sentence. To put it another way it turns what modifies it into a noun, which can then serve as a subject, an object etc. Here, the sentence  マッカーサーが自分で作って見た, "MacArthur tried making one himself" or "MacArthur made it himself as an experiment", becomes a noun, which can be rendered into English as "The thing MacArthur tried making himself", or "What MacArthur tried making himself". This noun phrase is marked with  が as the subject of the verb である. The whole therefore means, in an over-literal translation, "What MacArthur tried making himself is Map A". In this sentence it is the first part that the writer regards as new information for the reader. The reader clearly knows there is a Map A because it is (presumably) there on the page, and the writer is supplying the new information that what this map represents is MacArthur's own effort at making a map of whatever-it-is. I would render this straightforwardly as "Map A represents MacArthur's own draft" or "MacArthur's own draft is shown as Map A".

Consider:

> バスに乗る     [Somebody] gets on a bus
>
> バスに乗るのを見た      I saw [somebody] get on a bus
>
> きのう、駅の前で田中さんがバスに乗るのを見た  I saw Tanaka-San get on a bus in front of the station yesterday
>
> きのう、駅の前でむかし英語を習った田中先生がバスに乗るのを見た    I saw my old English teacher Tanaka-San get on a bus in front of the station yesterday

And so on.

Comment: +1 but shouldn't it be written 作ってみた rather than 作って見た?

Comment: True, as it's an auxiliary, not a full verb. I stuck to the orthography in the question in order to avoid distracting attention from the salient point, but you're right  - not a good decision.

Comment: Not sure I quite get the point of Chocolate's edit. I presume it means "Tanaka-sense I, from whom I used to learn Em

Comment: Sorry, sent accidentally. I presume it means "Tanaka-sense I, from whom I use to learn English". Is this an improvement on  むかしの英語の先生の田中さん？(Genui

Comment: That puzzles me too. Not quite sure how SE works, but don't you need to put @Chocolate in front of your comment? Your comments went to me.

Comment: You'd call your former/old teacher with ～先生, not ～さん. You'd still call them as 先生 even if they had retired. むかしの英語の先生の田中先生 would make sense but doesn't sound very natural, and it doesn't really sound like the person was YOUR teacher. To say " **my** old English teacher Mr. Tanaka/Tanaka-sensei," I think you'd usually say like 昔英語を習った田中先生, 昔英語を教わった田中先生、中学の時の英語の田中先生、高校で英語を教わった田中先生、大学時代の英語の田中先生, etc.