# こと vs. の in this sentence

Tags: grammar

This is kind of a follow-up question to this one:
[Problem with のが in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/46538/problem-with-%e3%81%ae%e3%81%8c-in-this-sentence/46556?noredirect=1#comment83305_46556)

To give a quick overview, in this sentence そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**の**が地図Aである **の**　had a function I must admit I still can't really explain^^
To me it kind of works like a nominalizer, but if you follow the answers in the thread you will find that it is (also) something else.

However, I thought that this might be worth a new thread:
Could one replace の with こと here?
Both can be used as nominalizers, and maybe I can better differentiate between の as a mere nominalizer and の in the function of the respective construction above, if someone explains to me why こと can/can't be used here instead of の ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

の is called a nominalizer when it turns a verb into a noun that means "(the act of) ～ing".

> - **食べるの**が好きです。
>     I like eating.
> - 明日寿司を**食べるの**を楽しみにしています。
>     I am looking forward to eating sushi tomorrow.
> - 晩ご飯を**食べるの**と風呂に**入るの**、どっちがいい？
>     Which do you like, eating dinner or taking a bath?

This type of の is sometimes interchangeable with こと. For details see this question: [What is the difference between the nominalizers こと and の?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/1395/5010)

However in cleft sentences の does not do that.

> - 明日寿司を**食べるの**は太郎です。
>     It's Taro who will eat sushi tomorrow.
> - 明日太郎が**食べるの**は寿司です。
>     It's sushi that Taro will eat tomorrow.
> - 太郎が寿司を**食べるの**は明日です。
>     It's tomorrow that Taro will eat sushi.
> - 明日太郎が寿司を**食べるの**は銀座です。
>     It's in Ginza (town) that Taro will eat sushi tomorrow.
> - 明日太郎が寿司を**食べるの**は誕生日だからです。
>     It's because it's his birthday that he will eat sushi tomorrow.

In the first sentence の is a placeholder for a person (Taro); in the second sentence, a thing (sushi); in the third sentence, a certain time point (tomorrow); and in the last sentence, a reason!

If you treated this の as a nominalizer, the first sentence would be translated as something like "[×] Eating sushi tomorrow is Taro," which does not make sense.

Finally, this type of の is not interchangeable with こと. You have to always use の to form a cleft sentence.

Comment: そもそもこの場合「地図」は「こと」ではないような気がするのですが…

Comment: ごめんなさい、もう少し説明していただけると…

Comment: あ、すみませんでした。分裂文の焦点側を「こと」で締められないことの説明としては素晴らしいのですが、質問本文を見ると、質問者が「地図」という語を「こと」で受ける前提に立っています。この場合どっちみち「こと」は適用できない気がします。

Answer (score 2):

They are all natural as Japanese sentences and sound almost the same;

- そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**の**が地図Aである。
- そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**もの**が地図Aである。
- そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**地図**が地図Aである。

But,

- そこで、マッカーサーが自分で作って見た**こと**が地図Aである。
  This is not natural as a Japanese sentence.