# たんですから vs たからなんです

Tags: particle-から, cleft-sentences

[image]

> 私がこの町のことをよく知っているのは、 前に________。
>   1. 住んでいたんですから
>   2. 住んでいたからなんです

According to the answer key, the correct answer is 2.

I want to know why it is not answer 1.
What is the difference between たんですから and たからなんです?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 私がこの町のことをよく知っているのは、 前に住んでいたからなんです。
>   "The reason why I know this town well is, because I used to live here before."
>   "It is because I used to live here that I know this town well."

This is a cleft sentence. For more details on cleft sentences, please refer to [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/9831).

The ん(の) in なんです(なのです) is the explanatory の.

In the normal word order the sentence would be:

> 前に住んで**いたから**、私はこの町のことをよく知っているんです。
>   "Because I used to live here, I know this town well."

Here in the original/normal sentence you use 「いたから」 and not 「いたんですから」, so you use 「いたから」 in the cleft sentence, too. Also, you'd need to end the cleft sentence with 「～です。」, and therefore the correct answer should be #2.

> Normal sentence: 「XXXから、YYY(ん)です。」 "Because XXX, YYY."
>   → Cleft sentence: 「YYYなのは、XXXから(なん)です。」 "It's because XXX that YYY."

---

Example:

Normal word order: 優しいから、佐藤さんは人気があります。<sub>(or ある**ん**です using the explanatory の)</sub>
"Because Sato-san is kind, she is popular."
 ↓
Cleft sentence: 佐藤さんが人気があるのは、優しいからです。<sub>(or からな**ん**です using the explanatory の)</sub>
"It is because Sato-san is kind that she is popular."

Comment: However, sometimes I found ですから using at the end of sentence. Like this “これ以上何も言うことはありません、いいわけをするのはいやですから “.    So, I want to know why.

Comment: @GBBoss　これ以上何もいう事はありません、言い訳をするのは嫌ですから。 is not a cleft sentence. it's just an inversion/anastrophe. Its normal word order is 言い訳をするのは嫌ですから、これ以上何も言うことはありません。 and it's a polite way of saying 言い訳をするのは嫌だから、これ以上何もいう事はない。

Comment: i dont quite sure that I understand cleft sentence correct or not. In my understanding , It means when you want to emphasize something right?  Like this sentence のは、 前に________。 So, can I infer that if I found のは on the sentence. It always end up with からです right?

Comment: どうしてフライドチキンが好きですか？ B: 美味しいですから.   Or 美味しいからです   I think both answers are make sense for me.

Comment: 「どうしてフライドチキンが好きなんですか？」って聞いた方が自然です。返答は「美味しいからです。」のほうが自然です。

Comment: A cleft sentence doesn't always end with からです. eg 「山田さんがこのケーキを作りました。」Yamada-san made this cake. →「このケーキを作ったのは山田さんです。」 It is Yamada-san that made this cake.  基本はこの形です：「～～のは、・・・です。」"It is ... that ~~."

Answer (score 1):

> [接助］活用語の終止形に付く
>
> 1. 理由・原因を表す。「もう遅いから帰ろう」
> 2. (終助詞的に用いて）強い主張、決意を表す。「思い知らせてやるから」

Your example 1 is the number 2 usage and your example 2 is the number 1 usage. So your example 2 is appropriate for this answer.

Generally, から in ですから that is the end of a sentence is the numner 2 usage and から in からです is the numner 1 usage.

Comment: Can you translate number 2 , I dont quite sure that I translate it correct or not

Comment: Do you refer to the number 2 usage?

Comment: Yes I mean the number 2 usage.  Now , I know that ですから is connected between A ですから B. But, からです is used at the end of the sentence. However, sometimes I found ですから using at the end of sentence. Like this “これ以上何も言うことはありません、いいわけをするのはいやですから “.    So, I want to know why.

Comment: I think It's an inversion as chocolate said.