# What is the function of のは in this question?

Tags: grammar, nominalization, cleft-sentences

きさまがこの時代に来てタマゴからそうなるまで3年間かかったのは...?

Comment: That is not a sentence.  It is only a very long topic + は.  The whole predicate is left unsaid and is represented by the '.....' at the end.

Comment: Thank you, I changed the question. So the の and は are independent of each other?

Comment: 1. I see, thank you. 2. This is the full dialogue. The follow-up response is「いちどタマゴにもどってしまうとふたたび熟成するのに地中で3年...それだけ時間が必要なのだ 」3. So then the verb that is nominalized would be かかった, changing it from "take" to "taking"?

Comment: The の bit is nominalization (こと can also be used), you should find out about this first. Then read Naruto's answer below for は.

Comment: @MathieuBouville I think this way of using のは is clearly requesting for an explanation/reason, and it's not really interchangeable with こと(は) here.

Answer (score 5):

This is an "incomplete" [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010), and that のは is part of the grammar of cleft sentences. Do you understand the following simpler example of cleft sentence used to emphasize the reason?

> そこに山があるから、彼は山に登る。
>   He climbs because a mountain is there.
>
> 彼が山に登る**のは**、そこに山があるからだ。
>   It is because a mountain is there that he climbs.

And the sentence in question is an incomplete version of this grammar. The speaker left the latter half of the sentence (the reason part) unsaid, probably because he is expecting the other party will continue his sentence and explain the matter. In other words, it's like ending an English sentence with "because...".

> 彼が山に登る**のは**…
>   He climbs, *because*...
>
> きさまがこの時代に来てタマゴからそうなるまで3年間かかった**のは**...?
>   So, after coming to this era, you spent three years to transform from the egg form to that form, *and that's because*...?