# この仕事が無事に＿ ＿ ⊛ ＿、心から感謝している。

Tags: word-choice, syntax, jlpt, shinkanzen-master

After reviewing some old 新完全マスター material I came across this sentence, which took me a bit to parse:

> この仕事が無事に＿ ＿ ⊛ ＿、心から感謝している。
>
> 1. チームワークが
> 2. 終わるのは
> 3. ほかならず
> 4. よかったからに

My "immersion reflexes" kicked in and I selected 2-1-**4**-3. I got it right, but the solutions manual just provides the correct answer (not the actual order).

My thought process is the following:
First of all the only thing that can fill the first gap is 終わるのは (無事に終わるのは has such a natural flow).
Also, 3 must follow 4 since 4 ends in に, thus completing the pattern にほかならない・ならず.
Putting it all together 1 has to fit the 2nd spot (since putting it on spot 4 is completely invalid), thus getting the final sentence:

> この仕事が無事に終わるのはチームワークがよかったからにほかならず、心から感謝している。

which roughly translates to something like:

> This job was completed successfully only because of good teamwork, for which I am sincerely grateful.

Since I couldn't confirm this anywhere, I wanted a second opinion.

If it is indeed correct, let this work as a reference for the next person who might be wondering the same thing.

Comment: "Putting it all together 2 has to fit the 2nd spot (since putting it on spot 4 is completely invalid), thus getting the final sentence:" I think you have a typo here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you've missed the cleft sentence grammar? This is a combination of the following two patterns:

- A(だ)からB ⟶ BのはA(だ)からだ ("It's because (of) A that B")
  <sub>(A cleft sentence where the reason part (から) has been pulled out for emphasis. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/65126/5010))</sub>
- Aだ ("is A") ⟶ Aにほかならない ("is nothing but A")

Putting the two together, we get:

- BのはA(だ)からにほかならない ("It's exactly because (of) A that B")

Thus a literal translation is:

> この仕事が無事に終わるのはチームワークがよかったからにほかならず、心から感謝している。
> It's exactly because our teamwork was good that this job was completed successfully, (so) I'm sincerely grateful.

Your translation attempt is correct, too.