# Meaning of 挙げてきた in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning

> 実際問題として、近年多くの企業が新卒求職者に求める能力として挙げてきたのが、まさにコミュニケーション能力、「コミュ力」なのであった。

The 挙げてきた part is confusing me, I can't seem to find a definition of this word. In general struggling to translate this sentence and understanding some of the meaning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

挙げる is a simple transitive verb meaning "to nominate", "to mention" or "to list".

(～て)くる is one of the Japanese [subsidiary verbs](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010). It adds the nuance of "over time" and/or "toward/for us" (if this survey was conducted by the author), but it may be left untranslated in this case. See: [Difference between -ていく and -てくる](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/676/5010)

In case you've missed it, this sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/19204/5010). The object of 挙げる is コミュニケーション能力, which was pulled out for emphasis.

> 実際問題として、近年多くの企業が新卒求職者に求める能力として挙げてきたのが、まさにコミュニケーション能力、「コミュ力」なのであった。
>
> As a matter of fact, it is this communication ability, or *comyu-ryoku*, that many companies have recently mentioned as an ability they demand of job-seeking students.