# 能力や装飾を施している meaning in this context,

Tags: meaning

The speaker was hired by the queen to manufacture enhanced armour, but not many of the 貴族騎士 has requested an order as of now. The speaker is trying to give his special armour as a gift to a poor soldier that did the speaker some favours in the past.

> poor soldier「・・・私にはあなたに依頼するようなお金はありませんよ」
>
> 「とんでもない、お金はいりませんよ」
>
> 「貴族騎士からお代をいただいているのは、殿下が定めた基準を超える能力や装飾を施しているからです」
>
> 「本来は私の技術を軍に生かすというのが、殿下のお考えーーー過度な物でなければ、普及優先のためお代は貰いません」

In regards to what i charge the nobility, the  "能力や装飾を施している" exceeds the standard the queen has set, so i don't need money from you.

Originally, the queen's idea was that my craft is to be used by our forces, --- if it's not too extreme, for the sake of prioritizing the popularity  of the armour, payment isn't needed .

I find it difficult to fit a definition J or E, for 能力や装飾を施す in this context

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 能力や装飾を施す itself is simply "to add/apply ability and embellishment". 施す has several meanings, but here it roughly means "to add (some decorative element)". For example you can say 帽子に刺繍を施す, 重要な単語に下線を施す, 筐体に撥水加工を施す.
- AのはBからだ is a common [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) used to emphasize a reason, and it's translated as "It's because B that A" or "A because B". For example, ダウンボートされるのは調べないからだ means "It's because you don't research that you get downvotes".
- 殿下が定めた基準を超える is a relative clause that modifies the noun(s) 能力や装飾.

> 貴族騎士からお代をいただいている**のは**、((殿下が定めた→)基準を超える→)能力や装飾を施している**からです**。
>
> I charge noble knights (for the enchantment) because (when I charge them) I add (to the armors) abilities and embellishment that exceed the standard that Queen has set.

Comment: i see, when i read it i was stuck on 殿下が定めた基準 being around how much to charge, not how much to enhance the armour. Starting off with "お代をいただいているのは" really made it difficult to distance myself from that idea