# Does ~のは...ためです make sense?

Tags: grammar, cleft-sentences

There's a sentence in a Japanese grammar book describing the differences between transitive and intransitive verbs.

> 自動詞: XがVi
>
> 他動詞: YがXをVt
>
> 自動詞と他動詞の違いは、自動詞の場合は、自然力の影響などで出来事が起こったのであって、そこには人間などの意志 (意図) は含まれていない、ととらえられているのに対し、他動詞の場合は、人間などが意志 (意図) 的にその出来事を引き起こした、ととらえられているというところにあります。
>
> 一方、そうした違いにも関わらず、Xが両者に**共通しているのは**、このXがどちらの場合でも影響の受け手としてとらえられている**ためです**。

In my reading of this, 「Xが両者に共通しているの」 means "the quality/characteristic which X shares in both cases", so the use of ~ためです ("for / due to ~") at the end confuses me. I would think the most sensible ending would be ~とらえられている**こと**です, since 「こと」 nominalizes to a noun.

What nuance or meaning am I not understanding?

Comment: In the first clause, it's not that there's something about "X" that's being shared, it's that "X" itself is being shared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ～のは～(ため)だ forms a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010). In cleft sentences, you can say ～からだ, ～までだ, ～へだ, ～とだ and so on (and even sometimes ～をだ and ～がだ).

- お金がなかったため買わなかった。
  I didn't buy it because I had no money.
- 買わなかったのはお金がなかったためだ。
  It's because I had no money that I didn't buy it.

Xが両者に共通している usually means "They both have X in common". So the sentence means "Despite such differences, they both have X in common **because** this X is regarded as the recipient of the effect in both cases".

<sup>(But I admit I'm translating this without fully understanding what the author wants to say. If my translation didn't make sense to you, please share what そうした違い actually refers to. And if there are example sentences around this, it would greatly help.)</sup>