# What does の in this sentence do/mean?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, nominalization

> 最近、忙しくて。昨日だって帰ったの１２時すぎだったよ。

Please explain the use of の in the above sentence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This の is a special noun used to form [cleft sentences](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010). English speakers use [preparatory *it*](https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/preparatory-subject/) for this type of sentence. Japanese speakers use の.

From this:

> 12時過ぎに帰った。
> I got home past midnight.

We can form the following cleft sentence:

> 帰ったのは12時過ぎだった。
> It was past midnight that I got home.

And we can drop は in casual speech:

> 帰ったの12時過ぎだった(よ)。
> It was past midnight that I got home.

Comment: Just out of interest do you think it is inaccurate to claim that の is a nominaliser for cleft sentences like this? It doesn't seem to quite work the way I normally think of nominalisers but it is surely turning 帰った into a noun.

Comment: @user3856370 It's not inaccurate to say a nominalizer is a special noun, either. I tend to use the word nominalizer only when you can translate that part by adding "-ing". If "(My) having gotten home was past midnight" is enough as a translation, we can call this a nominalizer, but this it not the most natural translation...