# ~なくする negative verb and する grammar

Tags: grammar, conjugations

> 一人ぽっちでいられなくしたのはお前 (Spoken)

Is this just like the なくなる grammar (e.g. 食べなくなる) but with する implying it was done by someone?

Comment: With regard to questions like this one, I wonder if it's worth posting just a three letter answer: "_yes_".

Answer (score 3):

～くなる and [～くする](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%81%84-adjective-%E3%81%8F%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B-ku-suru-meaning/) are fundamentally different. For example:

- 赤くなる
  to become red / to turn red
- 赤くする
  to make (something) red

Likewise:

- 一人ぽっちでいられなくなる
  to become unable to be alone
- 一人ぽっちでいられなくする
  to make [someone] unable to be alone

And the original sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) where お前 has been pulled out for emphasis.

- 一人ぽっちでいられなくしたのはお前(だ)。
  It's *you* who made [someone] unable to be alone.
  <sup>(i.e., It's you who made [someone] prone to suffer from loneliness.)</sup>

Who this "someone" is depends on the context. It can be a third person, the listener or the speaker themself. If this "someone" is the speaker, the sentence roughly means something like "You made me unable to live alone without you anymore."