# 「昨日ここへ来たのはだれですか」Is の short for 者?

Tags: grammar, particle-の, cleft-sentences

> 昨日ここへ来たのはだれですか
>
> Book translation: who is the one who came here yesterday?

My understanding is the following: 「昨日ここへ来た」 is a relative clause modifying the pronoun 「の」 to mean "the one who came here yesterday", then は marks it as the topic. Because the interrogative word だれ is used, "the one" must be a person, so we use "who".

Now, can we replace 「の」 with 「者」? If so, would it be redundant because 「だれ」 is used?

> 昨日ここへ来た者はだれですか

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130747/discussion-on-question-by-nameless-is--short-for-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntactically, this の is a noun, and everything before it is a relative clause. But I think it's best to treat this の as "some special noun working as a placeholder". It's also different from what we usually call a nominalizer (which turns 見る "see" to 見るの "seeing", etc.).

Your sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010), a special construction to focus a certain part of a sentence. This の roughly corresponds to the "placeholder *it*" in English cleft sentences like "*It*'s John who ate the cake". You can see that this *it* is specially referring to a person, which is odd outside of this construction. Likewise, の in a cleft sentence is a special noun which is used in place of many things including 者/人, 物, 場所/所 and 時/時間, and it is unlikely to be an abbreviation of any particular word.

- 昨日ここへ来た**の**はだれですか？
  昨日ここへ来た**人**はだれですか？
  Who was **it** that came here yesterday?
  <sub>(This can be rephrased as "Who was *the person who* came here yesterday?", but that does not mean this *it* is short for *person*.)</sub>
- 彼がここへ来た**の**はいつですか？
  彼がここへ来た**時間**はいつですか？
  When was **it** that he came here?
- 昨日彼が来た**の**はどこですか？
  昨日彼が来た**場所**はどこですか？
  Where was **it** that he came yesterday?
- 昨日彼がここへ来た**の**は何故ですか？
  Why was **it** that he came here yesterday?
  <sub>(For this one, I don't know how to rewrite this using a normal noun and a normal relative clause)</sub>