# Meaning of ノッて来ん

Tags: words, katakana, kana-usage

> 誰か誘って遊び行こうかとおもったけど、**ノッて来ん**の男のダチばっかりでさぁ…

I can understand the first half of the sentence just fine, but what does the character mean when he refers to his friends as "ノッて来ん"? Is it some form of slang or colloquial speech?

Comment: If you're curious why のってくるの changes to のってくんの, see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/61959/5010).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a colloquial version of のってくる, where のる means *to accept invitation, join* (def #5 [大辞泉](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%82%8B/#jn-172646) or def #7 [プログレッシブ和英中辞典](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E3%81%AE%E3%82%8B/#je-59306)) and る is changed to ん. It means the speaker asks around for going out, and it is only guy-friends **who are willing to join** (ノッて来んの). Note that は is omitted and the part is a cleft sentence: ノッて来んの**は**男のダチばっかりだ. (Edited according to naruto's comment. [This](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/93338/45489) may also be relevant for what this の is, but practically you shouldn't worry too much.)

To me, the mix of katakana/kanji is slightly odd. のる is often written in katakana in the sense that the subject gets higher 'momentum' (in abstract sense, See def #10 in the 大辞泉), which to some extent overlaps in the sense being used.

Comment: You beat me to it! I thought that ノッて来んの is short for 乗ってくるのは

Comment: @JimmyYang Right, I should mention は is omitted. Edited.

Comment: 重箱の隅で恐縮ですが、この「の」は分裂文に定型的に現れる形式名詞の「の」であって、「やつ」のような何か具体的な名詞の置き換えだとは言わない方がいい気もします。[これ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/90830/5010)を見ていただけると。