# What is the difference between から and からで?

Tags: grammar

I sometimes see the construction "clause+からで" to introduce a reason. For example,

> ふと、普段足を止めない児童書の棚の前で立ち止まったのは、低い書棚の一番上に表紙を見せる形で置かれた絵本の、その表紙に見覚えがあった**からで**、年季の入って紙の古いそれをシンは取り上げる。

86─エイティシックス─Ep.2 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈上〉
安里アサト

I’m wondering if there is any difference between から and からで when it comes to introducing some reason? Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 4):

This で is the te-form of だ, and it is used to join the following two sentences (i.e., this is a compound sentence):

1. ふと、普段足を止めない児童書の棚の前で立ち止まった**のは**、低い書棚の一番上に表紙を見せる形で置かれた絵本の、その表紙に見覚えがあった**からだ**。
   **It was because** he recognized the cover of a picture book placed at the top of a bookshelf **that** he suddenly stopped in front of the bookshelf for children's books he usually passes.
2. 年季の入って紙の古いそれをシンは取り上げる。

The first sentence is a [cleft sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/19208/5010) that focuses on the reason part. AがVした**のは**B**からだ** means "It is because B that A V". That is, 見覚えがあった is the reason for 立ち止まった, not 取り上げた.